# Escrever um arquivo .ods o resultado de uma consulta a uma api

Tags: javascript, node.js

Boa tarde a todos, eu quero que após fazer uma consulta em uma api, seja gerado em um arquivo.ods o resultado dessa consulta, estou usando o file system para isso. Ao pedir pra imprimir enquanto está no laço ele mostra perfeito o resultado, porém, no arquivo gerado ele fica [object][object] alguém pode me explicar o porque?
segue o código

````
const fs = require('fs')
const https = require('https')
const url = 'linkescondido.com'


async function getModulos(){
  const lista = []
  const agente = new https.Agent({
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  })
  for(i=0; i<20; i++){
    let response  = await axios.get(url, {
      httpsAgent: agente,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
        'Accept':'application/json',
        'Authorization':'Token token=tokenescondido###'
      },
      params:{
        page:i
      }
      
    })
    console.log(response.data);
    lista.push(response.data)
       

  }

 console.log(lista.length);
 fs.writeFileSync('lista.txt', lista.join('\n'))

}

getModulos() ```
````

Comment: O assunto é interessante mas a pergunta está mal formulada. O fato de usar ou não um arquivo `.ods` não possui relação com fato de objetos em Javascript ao serem convertidos em string apresentam a saída `[Object Object]`. A pergunta ficou tão confusa, que você perguntou *"...o arquivo gerado ele fica [object][object] alguém pode me explicar o porque?..."* o usuário o respondeu *"...Se não quiseres que apareça [object Object] tens que converter em JSON...."* . Por favor, considere [edit] a pergunta, deixando o texto mais objetivo e trocando o código por um [mcve] focado no real problema.

Answer (score -3):

Se não quiseres que apareça [object Object] tens que converter em JSON.

```
lista.push(JSON.stringify(response.data));
```